# The set of finite "variations" of an unconditionally convergent series is pre-compact

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, compactness

**Proposition:** If $\sum x_i$ is an unconditionally convergent series in a Banach space $X$, then $S=\{\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_ix_i:n\in\mathbb N, \varepsilon_i=\pm1\}$ is pre-compact.

**Proof:**

1) [$S'=\{\sum^\infty \varepsilon_ix_i:\varepsilon_i=\pm1\}$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435573/the-set-of-variations-of-an-unconditionally-convergent-series-is-compact)

2) $2\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_ix_i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\varepsilon_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\varepsilon_i'x_i$

where $\varepsilon_i=\varepsilon_i'$ for $i=\overline{1,n}$

and $\varepsilon_i=-\varepsilon_i'$ for $i=\overline{n,\infty}$

3) Therefore, $S$ is pre-compact.

**Problem:** To prove that $S$ is pre-compact, it is enough to examine the limits of sequences in $S$ (since metric spaces are Hausdorff). Apparently, the proof does differently.

As far as I can interpret it, one can express any element in $S\over 2$ as a sum of two elements in $S'$. It does not follow, however, that $\overline {S\over 2}=S'$, which would nearly conclude the proof... How can I better understand this concept? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Edits have been made. @ChrisEagle

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: A question has now been explicitly stated, @Norbert.

Comment: Ivan, in proposition you state that $S$ is presompact. In paragraph 3) you are concluding $S$ is compact. Pleasy clarify

Comment: I apologize. It says as it should now. @Norbert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparentlly $$S\subset \frac{S'+S'}{2}$$ Also addition and multiplication are continuous in Banach spaces, therefore $\frac{S'+S'}{2}$ is compact. Therefore, $S$ is pre-compact as a subset of a compact set. q.e.d.